# Published .Net Core C# console app not finding COM dependency ("An assembly specified in the app dependencies manifest was not found")?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, console-application

I'm attempting to publish a .net core c# console app (tested in both debug and release). However when I run the published exe, I receive the error message "An assembly specified in the app dependencies manifest was not found". It can't locate the .dll for my COM dependency "Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel". My .csproj file has the following itemgroup for it:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Excel.dll">
    <Guid>00020813-0000-0000-c000-000000000046</Guid>
    <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
    <VersionMinor>9</VersionMinor>
    <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
    <Lcid>0</Lcid>
    <Isolated>false</Isolated>
  </COMReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I've found similar questions with various answers, usually tweaking the publish settings, but nothing's worked for me so far. I'm using win-64 runtime and I've tried both deployment modes (framework dependent and self-contained). All of my dependencies are up-to-date.

Comment: there is a high chance that your target machine does not have Excel installed. Of course it works on your dev machine when there is some Excel version installed. By using Office Interop, the target machine would need Excel installed. You can consider using other libraries as an alternative to Excel (if possible). Such libraries do not require Office Interop.

Comment: @KingKing Sadly even running the published file on my dev machine doesn't work (which has Excel installed). I have yet to find an alternative library that can refresh connections and pivots, and that's open source. Thanks for your help.